# Efficiently awaiting for resources

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I wonder what would be the most efficient solution to this problem.

I have a multithreaded database implementation (LevelDB, for example) and I want it to handle synchronization, since it can do it better. However, I want to initialize the database asynchronously, without blocking any thread unless they somehow want to use the database before it has been opened.

Something along the lines of:

```
public class Storage {
  Database db;

  public Storage() {
    open();
  }

  private void open() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // attempt to open db here, i.e. change the value of Storage.db from null
        // into Object
      }
    }).run();
  }

  public void accessMethod() {
    // this method should only use a non-null Storage.db value, it should block
    // until the thread above does not set the value of db to be an Object
  }

  public void nonAccessMethod() {
    // this method is not concerned with the value inside Storage.db and should not 
    // block while the thread above is running
    // example: memory cached operations on the db which will be executed after
    // the thread above finishes and "unlocks" Storage.db
  }
}
```

I came up with this solution, but it is not very efficient:

```
public class Storage {
  ReentrantLock lock;

  Database db;

  public Storage() {
    lock = new ReentrantLock();

    open();
  }

  private void open() {
    lock.lock(); // to be released in thread below

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // heavy work here while populating Storage.db

        lock.unlock();
      }
    }).run();
  }

  // returns true if the database is not yet open and that we need to release
  // the lock once our code segment completes
  private boolean blockIfNotOpen() {
    if (lock.tryLock()) {
      lock.unlock();       // <<   this code segment sucks

      return false;
    } else {
      lock.lock();

      return true;
    }
  }

  public void accessMethod() {
    boolean wasNotOpen = blockIfNotOpen();

    // "blocking" code here

    if (wasNotOpen) {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void nonAccessMethod() {
    // not concerned with Storage.db and therefore not trying to lock
  }
}
```

I don't like this solution because it still synchronizes access to the database in the implementation of Storage long after `Storage.db` has been populated, when in fact there is an underlying system inside DB which can handle concurrency better (example: DB exposes worker threads, etc.).

Synchronizing on the Storage object is not a solution since it will, well synchronize, all the time, instead of only when Storage.db is null.

Notes: I'm guaranteed that there will be no concurrent calls before Storage's constructor finishes, if you're worried about the lock. :) So, all concurrency happens after the constructor.

Comment: If I had to name this problem, it would be called a "Conditionally critical segment synchronization"

Comment: Can't you simply set `accessMethod()` to `synchronized`, and add a `if (db == null) build();` in it?

Comment: Firstly, use Thread::start, not Thread::run if you want your code to execute in separate thread. Secondly, I'd suggest some db initialization indicator - volatile boolean variable or something like that.

Comment: If you can, in all your threads that access the DB sooner or later, identify a point that is before the first such access: then this point would be the one to block on the lock.

Comment: @sp00m That is not a solution since Storage is synchronizing access (always) to the db, not the db implementation itself.

Comment: @krems Yep, for the Thread#run. Anyway, volatile boolean could work. It's a little less ugly than `tryLock() / unlock()`, but is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution would be using `ReadWriteLock` - `writeLock().lock()` in constructor, `writeLock().unlock()` after the db is initialized and the `readLock()` is used from the db consumers.

Another option, use Future:

```
public class Storage {
    private final Future<Database> dbFuture = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(
        new Callable<Database>()
        {
            public Database call()
            {
               return new Database(...);//Long running DB initialisation
            }
        }
    );

    public void accessMethod()
    {
       Database db = dbFuture.get();// will wait while the call() is not completed yet.
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! Futures! That is I guess the most intuitive solution by far. Don't know how efficient it is, but I'm guessing plenty. :)

Comment: Oh, I think the code has an issue - the Executor should be shut down, otherwise the thread will be hanging forever. However, I guess a real app would have the executor injected outside and probably shared with other objects.

Comment: Yeah. :) But it's OK.